# How to query the next row

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table containing a column AGE contains these values:

```
5
2
10
4
1
```

How can I select everything after where AGE=2 and the next row has Age=10?

My desired results should be:

```
4
1
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL (including MySQL) tables are considered to be "unordered" and the sequence of data entry is not guaranteed to be the sequence of rows when you query that data. The "default order" of any data can be whatever happens as the database reads from storage - which is not guaranteed to be in any sensible order.

You HAVE to apply an ORDER BY clause to guarantee a predictable sequence.

So if you are relying on a sequence have some way to replicate that sequence through an order by clause.

Comment: i have an ID column too.
so if i orderBy ID how can i achieve my desired results

Comment: Possibly.  You need to provide better sample data and tells us the mysql version. This would be simpler if using mysql 8 (new features)